# Why does my timeline show javascript memory leak, but heap snapshot does not?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

Leaving a page open for 2 minutes and recording with Chrome dev tools, I get a saw tooth pattern BUT the JS heap does not return back to it's original level - rather, for each garbage collection it remains a bit higher until it eventually crashes:

[image: Performance]

Conventional wisdom suggests taking 2 heap snapshots over a period of time and comparing them to isolate the problem.  Before a heap snapshot, a garbage collection automatically takes place.  Expected results would be that heap snapshot number 1 shows a baseline of ~19 MB of heap, and snapshot 2 shows at least 22 MB after 2 minutes.  Instead, snapshot 2 actually shows *less* heap

[image: Snapshots]

What should I do now to find the leak?

Answer (score 0):

It might have just been a fluke. Try taking multiple snapshots. Like, one every 10 seconds, ten times.

Try [Allocation Timelines](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/#identify_js_heap_memory_leaks_with_allocation_timelines) and [Allocation Profiles](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/#allocation-profile), too. Allocation Timelines show you when memory is getting allocated, in a realtime graph. Profiles show you what functions allocate the most memory.